# Oracle locks index on multiple inserts

Tags: oracle, hibernate, indexing, database-partitioning, database-locking

I have this problem, and has not found a solution for it yet:

I have a application with multiple tables (like most applications).

Two of the tables are:

```
TB_POLICY
---------
id number(18) : PK
... some other columns

TB_REDEMPTION
-------------
id number(18) : PK
fk_policy number(18) : NOT NULL, FK
... some other columns
```

The `TB_POLICY` is partitioned by hash of some of its fields, and `TB_REDEMPTION` is partitioned by reference on `fk_policy` relation.

Table `TB_POLICY` contains about 50,000 records and table `TB_REDEMPTION` contains about 25,000,000 records.

There is a use-case in which the application inserts a single record in `TB_POLICY` and lots of records (about 200-300 records) in `TB_REDEMPTION` in a single transaction.

When I mark a break-point in my code, after all the inserts (in both tables), and before committing the transaction, there is no way to insert another record into `TB_REDEMPTION` from another database connection (even directly from SQL*Plus) - it just waits!

We analyzed many things and found out that a lock is happened on `PK_REDEMPTION` (primary key index of the `TB_REDEMPTION` ).

How can I prevent this lock? I searched the web and did not find anything about an index lock during insert.

I shall mention that this application is web-based and there are many concurrent users using the same use-case, and locking the primary key index by a user, prevents other users' job, and has a very bad performance effect on application.

Another point, the application is developed by Spring/Hibernate, so transaction management is done by Spring, and DML statements are created by Hibernate. And we are using Oracle 11g.

Comment: Are you sure you have an index on your FK?  Did you enable hibernate tracing to see exactly what the SQL statement are that are being executed?

Comment: Yes there is an index on the FK.

Comment: There are lots of SQL statements (mostly selects), including 1 insert statement on `TB_POLICY` and hundreds on insert statements on `TB_REDEMPTION`, and hundreds on a table which is a child of `TB_REDEMPTION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem, the TB_REDEMPTION had another foreign key `FK_PAY` which was unique but nullable.

It was defined as:

```
alter table tb_redemption add constraint uk_rdm_pay unique(fk_pay);
```

But the problem is Oracle does not add record to index if all of index properties are null. So when inserting a record with `fk_pay` equals to null, Oracle locked the table not the record in index, and that was root of problem.

I solved the problem by dropping the unique constraint and defining following unique index:

```
create unique index ux_rdm_pay on tb_redemption(fk_pay, case when fk_pay is null then id end);
```

So the unique index mandates the uniqueness of the relationship, and the index's fields will never be `null` together, so all records in table would be indexed and it prevents table lock.

Comment: I'd consider using a more simple index definition: (fk_pay, 0). This will also never be null, of course, but the optimiser is also aware of that.

Comment: Which one is better then?

Comment: (fk_pay, 0) ought to be.

Comment: @DavidAldridge but then it can not be unique index to enforce uniqueness of `fk_pay`

Comment: Ah yes - tell you what, in that case I'd just add the extra 0 as the last column of three, just so the optimiser knows that every row is included.

Comment: But `id` is primary key, so it will never be null (it has a `not null` constraint), so the optimizer knows that. ;)

Comment: If you: "select count(*) from ... where  fk_pay is null", does the optimiser use the index?

Comment: It may not infer that the index is guaranteed to contain all rows then -- or it may just not be as efficient as a full table scan if the table is narrow. Adding the extra column of 0 might change the former.

Comment: Could someone verify the following described behaviour in general?
"So when inserting a record with fk_pay equals to null, Oracle locked the table not the record in index"